# Can't click on menu item in live-cd after using gparted

Tags: unity, gparted, menu, appmenu

I'm trying out the new 16.04 desktop Xenial Xerus Live CD, and I've come upon a very peculiar thing: When I open the menu, I can select anything like normal, however when I open `gparted` and click on anything, then it forever locks out my ability to select anything from the menu thereafter.

**Note** that I can actually open `gparted` and close it without interacting, and the menu will continue to work.

**Note** that I can still launch `terminal` from the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

It doesn't freeze up, I can type backspace and type anything else in and the search works just fine and even right click and click the <kbd>Launch</kbd> button, but the application will never start. The only way I have been able to get the menu functionality back is to reboot.

[image: screenshot that nothing can be selected from menu]

Comment: LiveCD is always a quirky  thing to use. It is only meant to test a system for compatibility or boot a system to fix something. It doesn't work 100% with all systems. Also, your CD image may have errors on it.